# ¿Cómo obtener el tiempo que lleva un usuario sin utilizar mi app en android studio?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notificaciones, android-notifications

Lo que busco es que mi aplicación en android envíe una notificación después de ciertos días sin interactuar con mi aplicación, se como lanzar la notificación push por medio de firebase(así sería como la mandaría) con java, pero no tengo idea de como saber cuánto tiempo lleva sin uso y como comprobarlo en segundo plano. Gracias.

Comment: Cuando el usuario use la app haz que envíe información de la conexión a un servidor, firebase por ejemplo. Luego consultas el tiempo que ese usuario ha estado sin usar la app y le envías la notificación. No es necesario que la app se mantenga activa en segundo plano para eso.

Comment: @Lobos ¿de qué manera haría la consulta del tiempo en firebase automáticamente para todos los usuarios?, y qué información habría que guardar en firebase, puedes darme una idea por fa?

Comment: Cuando mencionas que sabes como enviar notificaciones push, las envías a un usuario específico?

Comment: A usuario específico o por topic, en este caso supongo que sería el específico pero la manera en que sé hacerlo es por solicitud desde la app

Comment: Está esta opción https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?authuser=0#data_messages. Permite enviar un mensaje con datos a la app, de esa forma se podría enviar el mensaje a todos los clientes, cuando el cliente lo reciba puede revisar su ultima conexión (guardada previamente) y decidir si mostrar una notificación o no.

Comment: También puedes usar AlarmManager, de la misma forma, revisar la última conexión del usuario y mostrar su notificación, para este último todo se hace en local.

Comment: Buenas ideas, pero estaba checando la documentación y en la primera opción habría que estar en primer plano la aplicación para procesar dichos datos, sino la mostraría a todos, por lo tanto no me funcionaría, entonces tendría que ser individual a cada usuario por separada, ahora voy a revisar la documentación de AlarmManager, no sé si se puede ejecutar en segundo plano, o aún así habría que tener un algoritmo en la nube ejecutándose para evaluar las últimas conexiones y enviar la notificación por individua

Comment: Puedes guardar un timestamp cada vez que el usuario mate la aplicación y, al mandar la notificación, recuperar el timestamp, miras el actual, calculas la diferencia y realizas la acción oportuna.  Mira también WorkManager para trabajar de forma asíncrona en background.  Puede haber mejores soluciones usando Firebase pero las desconozco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné almacenando la fecha en un shared preference en el método onCreate de la clase main, y con un periodic work manager comparé las fechas entre la fecha actual y la almacenada en nuestro shared preference, y en mi caso a la fecha almacenada le agregué 3 días con el método add de la clase Date y compare si la fecha almacenada más 3 días es menor a la fecha actual con el método before() de la clase Calendar (haciendo los respectivos casteos en su momento).